# How can I make the tags on my tumblr theme appear?

Tags: themes, tumblr, tumblr-themes

my tumblr theme hides the tags in a post when you don't click the post. is there a way to make the tags appear all the time?

[image: this is when you don't click on the post]

[image: and this is when you do].

I've tried writing

```
{block:HasTags}
    <ul class="tags">
        {block:Tags}<li><a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a></li>{/block:Tags}
    </ul>
{/block:HasTags}
```

inside {block: Posts} and even after it, but it doesn't work. here's a link to the html code of my theme: pastebin.com/awQUSraA

Comment: Can you actually provide a link to your blog? This will be in the css.

Answer (score 1):

It seems tags are hidden on the index page:

```
.tags {
    margin-top:5px;
    font-style:italic;
    {block:indexpage}display:none;{/block:indexpage}
}
```

Remove `{block:indexpage}display:none;{/block:indexpage}` and they should be visible.